# On mobiles (Ios/Android) display numberpad with decimal and percentage symbols

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have done lot of research and tried several regex patterns on html fields to get number pad displayed with decimal and percentage for **interest rate fields**, but no luck yet. I would be even fine if the keypad displays numbers and all symbols by default. Note that rate fields are text fields because they contain percent (%). Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number">
<input type="tel">
```

This will trigger number pad in mobile phones.

On iOS **type='number'** pulls up the full keyboard with numbers visible, whereas **type='tel'** pulls up the number pad.

On Android, both **number** and **tel** pull up the number pad

Comment: type="number" doesn't allow percent (%) on the field. Whereas "tel" doesn't provide decimal and %. So these two options doesn't work for me.